# How do you place in front of image in html and css so that you can read it?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

So I am trying to make the `<h1></h1>` above the image so that you can read it, but it randomly appears at the left bottom of the screen. I am doing this with vertical grid-columns so maybe that is the problem. Can somebody see what I am doing wrong and help me out?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
}

.container .beginpagina {
  grid-column: 1 / 17;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
}

.container .beginpagina img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  filter: blur(0.7px);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 60%, 50% 78%, 0 60%, 0 0);
}

.container .beginpagina h1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="beginpagina">
    <img src="img/universe3.jpeg" />
    <h1>Beginpagina</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CSS-Grid you do not need to use positioning. Just place the items in the same grid-cell.

For layering, just adjust the `z-index` of the `h1`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


.container {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
}

.container .beginpagina {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  display:grid
}

.container .beginpagina img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  filter: blur(0.7px);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 60%, 50% 78%, 0 60%, 0 0);
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column:1;
}

.container .beginpagina h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column:1;
  z-index:2;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="beginpagina">
  <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/3999/chicago_dual_monitor-2560x1024.jpg" />
    <h1>Beginpagina</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your h1 "left" style,it relocate x position of your h1 element,and i suggest you must give "z-index" to your h1 element(to make sure your "h1" element keep appear and not layered with your ".beginpagina" element)

```
.container .beginpagina h1{
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I gave it position absolute and it is still not in front of the image. Do you have another solution? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: if you want the h1 in front of your img,you can give z-index to your h1,example: h1 { z-index: 1; },z-index style will make your h1 text in front of your image.